# How can I create filename.TAR.GZ (ext. In upper case only) using Python tarfile package

Tags: python-3.x, tarfile

I am using the `tarfile` package for python.

```
Tar = tarfile.open("filename.tar.gz" mode='w:gz')
```

NOTE:
`tarfile.open("filename.**TAR.GZ**" mode='w:gz')`
is creating two levels of compression. no idea if it is a bug in the package

It is creating `"filename.tar.gz"`; however, for Unix constraints, we need `"filename.**TAR.GZ**"`(please note that extension is in uppercase.)

Could you please help me to create `filename.TAR.GZ`? I can use other packages than `tarfile` if available for my need.

Comment: filename.TAR.GZ and filename.tar.gz is the same; if you really want uppercase: `from shutil import move; move('filename.tar.gz','filename.TAR.GZ')`

Comment: Thank you very much Ningrong. It worked for me. However, using 7 zip Manager, I can see under filename.TAR.GZ, filename.tar (where the extension is in smaller case).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
import tarfile

file_to_add = "data.csv"
tar_archive = "file.TAR.GZ"

out = tarfile.open(tar_archive, "w:gz")
try:
    print(f"Adding {file_to_add}")
    out.add(file_to_add)
finally:
    print(f"Closing tar archive: {tar_archive}")
    out.close()

print(f"Contents of archive: {tar_archive}")
t = tarfile.open(tar_archive)
for member in t.getmembers():
    print(member.name)
```

Output

```
Adding data.csv
Closing tar archive: file.TAR.GZ
Contents of archive: file.TAR.GZ
data.csv
```

And if I do `ls` on the working dir, here's what's there:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, 'w' is used for "open for uncompressed writing". Hence GunZip/unix decompression might not work. Try "tar -xvf filename.TAR.GZ" in unix terminal

Comment: It was a typo on my side. I've fixed it. Thanks! No this should work just fine.